# Why can't I run my WatchOS 2 app?

Tags: watchkit, xcode7, apple-watch, watchos-2

It runs just fine on the iPhone. When I select the Watch App Target, however, it simply won't run on the watch.

I don't get any errors or anything. I can see the app downloading on the Watch sometimes; when it does download, it deletes itself the moment the download is complete.

I've tried uninstalling the watch app and reinstalling via the Apple Watch app on the iPhone, and the same thing happens: it downloads and deletes itself before I can run it.

I've also reset the watch, reset Xcode, deleted the iOS app, and just about everything else I could possibly think off, but I'm starting to lose my mind.

The problem started happening when I (attempted to) set up the Watch Connectivity framework. I don't know if this is related. I've been unable to verify that WC is working properly as I can't open the app.

I've been lucky enough to get it to actually load on the watch only a few times since integrating WC framework, but even when I have, all I got was the loading screen for about a minute each time.

**UPDATE:**

I'm now seeing some consistent behavior.

I'm now able to debug my app by launching the watch app via Xcode. The app icon does not appear at all on the watch when this happens, however. (Weirdly enough, it shows the launch screen for a different watch app when launching.) So I can't run the app at all unless it is launched from Xcode.

Also, I am not able to download the app to the watch via the phone. I want to be able to run it outside of debug mode, and I can't. When I attempt to install it from the Apple Watch iOS9 app, the install begins, I see the icon on the watch as it downloads, and just as it finishes, it deletes itself from the watch before I can run it. This just keeps happening.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this kind of sucks as an answer, but I've had enough.

I decided to copy all of my code and storyboards into a new Xcode project. The Watch App now works exactly as it should. Hopefully Apple sorts out these bugs in an update.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your Apple Watch device ID is in your provisioning profile.

Answer (score 1):

I believe repairing the watch would help as well. I had the same problem before and the only thing which helped was repairing the watch.

I also have other issues debugging the watch app properly - see my question here [Proper way to debug watchos2 app in XCode7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32760318/proper-way-to-debug-watchos2-app-in-xcode7)